# Change css by scrolling down and up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some code:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
           if($(window).scrollTop() > 50){

            $("#headerline").css("background","red");
            $("#header").hide();
            $("#header2").show();

           }else if($(window).scrollTop() < 50){

            $("#headerline").css("background","blue");
            $("#header2").hide();
            $("#header").show();

           }
    });
```

Nut when ever I scroll down it moves me back to the top.... I just want to change header css after the page is scrolled down by 100px and when it comes up to change again to main one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is working for me ... 
https://jsfiddle.net/vjc3t1d2/

```
 $(document).scroll(function() {
       if($(window).scrollTop() > 50){

        $("#headerline").css("background","red");
        $("#header").hide();
        $("#header2").show();

       }else if($(window).scrollTop() < 50){

        $("#headerline").css("background","blue");
        $("#header2").hide();
        $("#header").show();

       }
});
```

Comment: I will try it again there must be some problem in code before... I get automatically scrolled to the top after a get 50 lower. And when I remove else if ... if is working...

Comment: haha it is working now omg it doesn work with showing new divs beause divs are aabove and when I scroll down new div on top should appear and it focus on that div and scroll to the top and script says if it is scrolled to the top show fist ones....